# a2x fails to compile my manpage

Tags: asciidoc, manpage

I have a an Asciidoc document `foo.1.txt`, and, following the instructions [here](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/userguide.html#X1), I tried to compile it with `a2x` as follows:

```
a2x --doctype manpage --format manpage foo.1.txt
```

After this, I got the following error:

```
a2x: ERROR: "/usr/bin/asciidoc.py" --backend docbook -a 
"a2x-format=manpage"  --doctype manpage  --out-file 
"/home/koz/Documents/foo.1.xml" 
"/home/koz/Documents/foo.1.txt" returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I am unsure what is going on, or how I can even diagnose what is wrong. An xml file *is* generated in the same folder (titled `foo.1.xml`) as part of this process. All help is appreciated.

*EDIT:* Based on use of the `--verbose` flag, the problem seems to be in this section:

```
COPYING
----------
 Copyright \(C) 2015, Koz Ross <koz.ross@runbox.com>. Free use of this software
is granted under the terms of the GNU General Public License (GPL) version 3, or
any later version.
```

The complaint is: `[blockdef-listing] missing closing delimiter` on the line where `COPYING` is.

Comment: Try turning on the `--verbose` flag to get more output for debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
COPYING
----------
 Copyright \(C) 2015, Koz Ross <koz.ross@runbox.com>. Free use of this software
is granted under the terms of the GNU General Public License (GPL) version 3, or
any later version.
----------
```

works see http://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-writers-guide/#delimited-blocks
and becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN" "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd">
<?asciidoc-toc?>
<?asciidoc-numbered?>

<article lang="en">
<articleinfo>
    <date>2015-10-08</date>
</articleinfo>
<simpara>COPYING</simpara>
<screen> Copyright \(C) 2015, Koz Ross &lt;koz.ross@runbox.com&gt;. Free use of this software
is granted under the terms of the GNU General Public License (GPL) version 3, or
any later version.</screen>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you *so* much. Finally, an answer!